# Content Security Policy Problems when deploying Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, firefox

i want to deploy my django app and for that, in settings.py I set DEBUG=False
Since i did that, my website doesn't function anymore and in the Firefox Console, i get tons of error concerning the Content Security Policy. For the last two days i tried to fix this problem but can't seem to get the hang of it. This is my first django project i want to deploy, so it it possible I am missing something obvious. I am using some inline JavaScript and CSS and I am loading my jquery and ajax from googles CDN. I have set the CSP in the header of the base.html page like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
```

To test it i made it extremely unsafe, but still none if my scripts want to load. Why is that?

**The Console logs:**

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js”. account:106:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js”. account:107:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js”. account:108:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). account:18:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). account:32:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css (“style-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). 4 account
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). element-collapser.js:88:56
TypeError: i is undefined
infinite.min.a9e9aa085994.js:7:1207
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://www.privacypolicies.com/public/cookie-consent/3.1.0/cookie-consent.js”. account:114:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://www.privacypolicies.com/public/cookie-consent/3.1.0/cookie-consent.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://www.privacypolicies.com/public/cookie-consent/3.1.0/cookie-consent.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). account:115:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). account:126:1
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. preload.js:101:24
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js”. list-view:58:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js”. list-view:59:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js”. list-view:60:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). list-view:62:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). preload.js:169:52
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). 2 utils.js:35:9
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js”. list-view:84:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js”. list-view:85:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js”. list-view:86:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). list-view:17:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). list-view:77:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). list-view:88:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). 2 utils.js:35:9
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).
```

**My settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'mySecretKey'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
# DEBUG = int(os.environ.get('DEBUG', default=1))
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'account:dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = 'account:login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'account:logout'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"

# Application definition

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')  # not images, because i take that from the outer folder

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'book',
    'landing',
    'account',
    'club',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ajaximage',
    'el_pagination',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookclub.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',  # For EL-pagination
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bookclub.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'bookclubdb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',  
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',  # default value: 5432
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
AJAXIMAGE_AUTH_TEST = lambda u: True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Comment: How is your webserver configured with CSP?

Comment: I'm currently using localhost with default Django settings. I can post my settings.py if that is of any help.